# Is the term "spontaneous generation" found in the Vedas?

Tags: vedas

In Buddhism, is found the terms "opapatika/upapātika/upapāduka", translated as "spontaneous birth", "spontaneous arising" or/& "self-produced".

In Jainism is found a term "vīsasāpariṇayā", translated as "spontaneous generation".

Is there a similar term found in the Vedas? If so, please kindly quote some examples & contexts.

Comment: There are similar terms in the vedas.

Comment: Please kindly list them for me, Swami. Thank you

Comment: Swayambhu is the term, literally translates to self manifest

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Kind regards